# VSTO add-in BeforeAttachmentAddEvent catched by MS exchange server

Tags: c#, events, outlook, vsto

I'm writing `Outlook VSTO add-in` and I want to do size check before attachment add and if the file is too big I want to upload it to the cloud, so the code looks like:

```cs
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += InspectorsOnNewInspector;
        }

        private void InspectorsOnNewInspector(Inspector inspector)
        {
            if (inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem mailItem)
            {
                mailItem.BeforeAttachmentAdd += MailItemOnBeforeAttachmentAdd;
            }
        }

        private void MailItemOnBeforeAttachmentAdd(Attachment attachment, ref bool cancel)
        {
            // check and upload
            cancel = true;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
            //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///     Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///     the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "ArrangeThisQualifier")]
        [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "RedundantDelegateCreation")]
        [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "RedundantNameQualifier")]
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The problem is that all works fine until the file exceeds the size limit configured in MS Exchange. When it happens I get a notification message and after clicking "OK" `mailItem.BeforeAttachmentAdd` event doesn't fire. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your event handlers will work for more than a few seconds - you are setting the event handler either on a temporary variable (created by the compiler) in case of `Application.Inspectors.NewInspector` or on a local variable (when you set `mailItem.BeforeAttachmentAdd` event handler).

The object raising the events must be alive - store these objects on the global (class) level to make sure they are not collected by the Garbage Collector.

Also, there is no particular / guaranteed order of events, but I would imagine Outlook would always get the first pick. Worst case, you can patch IDropTarget implementation of the Outlook window and provide your own implementation. Not much you can do if an attachment is being inserted from the Ribbon...

Comment: I wrote the code above as it allows to test the case fast, it work a few times and then garbage collected, but thanks for your note
The problem is that outlook checks the file size limitation for attachment before event that I listen to, and if the file exceeds limitation I get "MessageBox" and the `BeforeAttachmentAdd` doesn't raise

Comment: Is it even possible to intercept Outlook check?

Comment: There is no particular / guaranteed order of events, but I would imagine Outlook would always get the first pick. Worst case, you can patch IDropTarget implementation of the Outlook window and provide your own implementation. Not much you can do if an attachment is being inserted from the Ribbon...

Comment: I think you should edit you answer or make another answer so I could accept it, thanks)